No ID in UserProfile created by OidcProfileCreator
I have a direct header client (using OpenID Connect) like this:
OidcConfiguration config = new OidcConfiguration();
config.setClientId(clientId);
config.setSecret(secret);
config.setDiscoveryURI(discoveryUri);
// additional settings of config

OidcClient oidcClient = new OidcClient(config);
OidcProfileCreator profileCreator = new OidcProfileCreator(config, oidcClient);
HeaderClient client = new HeaderClient("my-custom-header", "my-custom-prefix", profileCreator);

Authentication/ validation of the token works fine. The problem I have is in the OidcProfileCreator. The OidcProfileCreator never sets the ID in the UserProfile. The ID is set when there are OidcCredentials but not when there are TokenCredentials (see OidcProfileCreator.java:118). Why is that? Shouldn't the ID of the UserProfile be set by the JWT subject (sub) as well when there are token credentials?
I was expecting the created UserProfile to have the JWS claim sub (subject) to be set as the ID of the org.pac4j.core.profile.UserProfile.
I am using pac4j 5.7.3. But the profile creator acts the same in the current version.
Kind regards

The OidcProfileCreator assumes that the access token is an opaque identifier, thus it is set as the accessToken property of the profile.
We don't check if it's a JWT with claims.
